# Finding matrix $L$ such that the equality holds

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ invertible matrix with real entries and let $I$ be the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

**Question:** Is there a $4\times 4$ matrix $L$ such that:
$$L \begin{pmatrix}
A & I \\
I & A^{-1} 
\end{pmatrix}
L = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I \\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}
?$$

I've been testing a lot of possible matrices $L$, but I haven't been able to find some which solves the problem. I actually don't know for sure if such a matrix exists, but I believe that it does.

Comment: Has $L$ again real entries? It may be a singular matrix? What $L$ did you find for $A=I$?

Comment: I does not need to have real entries. It could be singular, too.

Comment: Actually $L$ has to be nonsingular by taking the determinant on both sides. Where does this question come from? Is it in the context of Lie algebras? Is it perhaps $LML^{-1}$ instead of $LML$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **all** invertible matrices $A$, there is no matrix $L$ satisfying the constraints. By applying a formula for the [determinant of a block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), we see that
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & I\\I & A^{-1} } = \det(AA^{-1} - I^2) = \det(0) = 0.
$$
So, the matrix on the left must have determinant zero, but the matrix on the right has non-zero determinant.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such matrix $L$ in general. For
given $A$ one can express the matrix equality as a system of $16$ polynomial equations in the $16$ variables of $L$, together with the four constant entries of $A$. By using the [Buchberger algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm), one can solve such a system by computing a Gröbner basis. It is immediate that, say, for $A=I$ there is no solution, because the Gröbner basis is equal to  $\{1\}$.

Indeed, taking the determinant shows that $A$ cannot be invertible. However, for singular matrices $A$ it makes sense to do this computation and to find all solutions $L$.

Comment: An easier approach: if $A = I$, then 
$$
M = \pmatrix{A & I\\ I & A^{-1}}
$$
is singular, which means that $LML$ must be singular, which means that $LML$ cannot be equal to the invertible matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&I\\I&0}.
$$

Comment: Could you show your calculations?

Comment: Dietrich, so there is no $L$ in general, but one could find such $L$ depending on the choice of $A$?

Comment: @Thomas The polynomial equations are like $a_1^2 + a_1a_3 + a_1a_9 + a_{13}a_2 + a_{13}a_4 + a_2a_5 + a_3a_9 + a_4a_5=0$ and so on, where $L=(a_{i})_{1\le i \le 16}$. The computation is helpful to see what is true. Afterwards it is better to find an argument using the determinant.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I think you should put the calculations in the answer

Comment: @DietrichBurder At least put some link of the methodology that you think is enough to get into your solution, if you do not want to write in full length. You just stated results and as it is your answer is difficult to read/understand for a non specialist. As it is, sounds more like a comment than an answer (in my opinion, but I may be wrong).

Comment: @Thomas Alright, I have edited my post.

Comment: @DietrichBurde great thanks